# php.ini file saves but does not show changes

Tags: php, ini, tweak

So I added a php info page checked the directory of my ini and changed and saved the new memory limit which I set to 64m. Changes are saved and when I reopen the file it shows me that it has been changed however when I go back to the php info page it is still set to 32m. How can I go about changing it since thats the only way I know how and that doesnt work.

after doing the above I have restarted the server no luck.

I am on centos vps and have ssh access

I have already said that I restarted the server yet I am getting replies telling me to restart it. 
I have already said that I have made a php info page and still getting replies telling me to create a php info page...

Loaded Configuration File   /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.ini

Please read the question properly before answering otherwise don't bother answering at all.

Comment: try to restart it again, or it seems you've changed the wrong php.ini file, check the directory.

Comment: How do you access the PHP.ini file ? Through file explorer or WAMP or XAMPP? Please check whether you have the write privileges or not.

Comment: I done a graceful server restart through my whm panel twice. I found the php ini file location using php info page. I edited it using flashfxp 5 ftp and saved exited fxp and re entered to check file and changes were saved. However when checking the php info page it still shows 32m and not 64m

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like you may need to restart the web server. Have you tried running php --ini on command line just to check the paths?

Comment: I have already stated that I restarted the server. I also tried finding it through putty/ssh but it still shows me the same path. php -i | grep php.ini                                   Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc
Loaded Configuration File => /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

with regatd for your positive question

firstly :
you should define your php.ini path

secondly after any change in php.ini , you should resart apache or iis server for applying changes

create a file php.ini and run it

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

you can see your php settings , please check your php.ini path

Answer (score 0):

As crazy as it can be restarting your site in IIS from the GUI does not restart php.
You need to open an elevated command prompt and type this command:

```
>iisreset /restart
```

and voilá you'll see that iis updates the changes in php.ini.